# what to put in React Higher Order Components logic

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

*Note: there is no code in this question and that is because I am looking for a more theoretical answer.*

I am new to HOC. I understand how to code it, but I'm not entirely sure what logic to put where or when to call it.

Right now I am working on some search functionality for my project and realized that I could share logic between the quick search result drop-down and the results page, since they are performing the same type of search.

The functionality I have is:

- **check repositories** - this checks that the data sent in is suitable
  for searching
- **prepare repositories** - this builds strings of parts of the data to make it easier to search
- **handle search** - this is where the actual search takes place
- **build results** - this is where the results are made so that they are "displayable" in the results component

The question is if these should only be generic functions in my HOC that can be called from my wrapped component, or if the functions should be run in the HOC before they are passed on?

For example, both **check repositories** and **prepare repositories** must be done before a search can be made. Therefore I am thinking that these can be done in the HOC and their results be sent as props to the wrapped component.

However, **handle search** is done when the user interacts with the component, maybe this should then be a function that the wrapped component can call?

And **build results** I am not sure about at all since it contains some display functionality, albeit generic, and perhaps it should remain in the wrapped component altogether?

Comment: I think it `check repository` and `prepare repository` can be be in the HOC and their props passed to the wrapped component. What exactly is wrapped anyways? `Handle search` can also be part of the HOC or its child if you want to only search after `check` and `prepare` or the child is mounted. It seems that you might want to render `build result` outside of the HOC, so you can pass a function to the HOC to update the parent with the built results.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. With "wrapped" I mean the component that is wrapped/enhanced (or whatever it is called) by the HOC.